# Redirecting dynamic url to new dynamic url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, dynamic

I am busting my head against a wall. I have a created an updated version of a website, and I have various dynamic pages that are being fed through PHP. The old pages had the following rewrites on them through htaccess:

OLD URL BEFORE REWRITE:

```
/directorio_hoteles/ean/hotel.php?cou=$1&hn=$2&city2=$3
```

OLD URL AFTER REWRITE:

```
/directorio_hoteles/Mexico/hotel336813/Villa_Mercedes_Petit_Hotel.htm
```

HERE IS HOW IT WAS CODED IN THE ORIGINAL HTACCESS:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/hotel([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.htm$ ean/hotel.php?cou=$1&hn=$2&city2=$3 [L]
```

I understand that this original format was not the best way to accomplish this, but this is what I have to work with, and the dynamic url's are already indexed in google. So I need to take the above already rewritten url and redirect (301) it to the new dynamic format which is:

NEW URL BEFORE REWRITE:

```
directorio-hoteles/index.php?p=hotel-page&a=$1&b=$2&c=$3
```

NEW URL AFTER REWRITE:

```
directorio-hoteles/hotel/Mexico/Villa_Mercedes_Petit_Hotel/336813
```

HERE IS HOW IT IS CODED IN THE NEW HTACCESS FILE:

```
RewriteRule    ^directorio-hoteles/hotel/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$     directorio-hoteles/index.php?p=hotel-page&a=$1&b=$2&c=$3   [NC,L]
```

So I can not wrap my head around how to get this:

```
/directorio_hoteles/Mexico/hotel336813/Villa_Mercedes_Petit_Hotel.htm
```

to redirect to this:

```
directorio-hoteles/hotel/Mexico/Villa_Mercedes_Petit_Hotel/336813
```

Any help would be BEYOND appreciated. Thank you in advance for any attempts to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as **first rule** in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(directorio_hoteles)/([^/]+)/(hotel)([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.htm$ /$1/$3/$2/$5/$4 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```